# My Rename function in JQuery does not work in Foreach sentence?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have create this function with JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/3uqF2/8/

Purpose of this function is to rename or in other word change text into another tekst. As you see in link, function works, but then I put it on my table, where I use "Foreach" sentence, and function works only for first row??? For other rows it puts both div's (see my link), and function do not work.

Here is my code in ASP.NET (MVC)

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>
         <a id="LINK1" href="#">Eng</a> /
         <a id="LINK2" href="#">Slo</a>
       </th> 
    </tr>
@foreach (var row in Model.Spremenljivke)
{
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <div id="lnk1">@String.Join("", ...)</div> //i did not put all code, it is too long
            <div id="lnk2">@String.Join("", ...)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 ...
}
```

Any idea why it works for only first row?

Comment: it is useful for you http://jsfiddle.net/3uqF2/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently with each iteration in your loop you will create 2 divs with repeating Ids. Perhaps you can do something more like:

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Spremenljivke)
{
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <div class="my-link" data-id="lnk1">@String.Join("", ...)</div>
            <div class="my-link" data-id="lnk2">@String.Join("", ...)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 ...
}
```

Then your links (as you can see your div `data` attribute is linked to the link with the same `class`):

```
<div class="status lnk1">Testiranje</div>
<div class="status lnk2">Testing</div>
```

And finally your jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // <-- you don't need multiple of those (1 is ok)
    $(".my-link").on("click", function() { 
        $(".status").hide();
        var linkId = $(this).data("id");
        $("." + linkId).show();
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uqF2/21/)

Comment: thanks man, but first row must always be seen... can it be implemented

Comment: @krnekires sure, I've added some CSS to remove it on purpose, here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uqF2/13/ is this the result you're looking for or ?

Comment: @krnekires or do you want only the first link to be shown at start ?

Comment: yes, @Dimitar, I nedd first row to be shown in start

Comment: it shows both rows and when I click link (slo e.g.) it shows first row

Comment: @krnekires did you check both of my fiddles (from the comments) ?

Comment: now I have try again, it works, but when I click link (Slo e.g.), all rows disepare, it stays only first row...

Comment: @krnekires Yeah, I think I misunderstood you the first time. I've updated my answer (and the fiddle link) -> http://jsfiddle.net/3uqF2/21/ is this more what you're looking for ?

Comment: @krnekires I'm just glad I could help :)

Comment: Is this solution more cleaner than the one I. Posted?

Answer (score 1):

Ids must be unique, use class instead like this:

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Spremenljivke)
{
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <div class="lnk1">@String.Join("", ...)</div> //i did not put all code, it is too long
            <div class="lnk2">@String.Join("", ...)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 ...
}
```

and in jquery:

```
 $("#LINK1").click(function () {
        $(".lnk2").hide()
        $(".lnk1").show()
    });
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xNG8k/)